# Create Map for IEnumerable to IEnumerable /List in automapper

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am having issue with Automapper when i have a collection.
Below is my situaion

**Bussiness Model**

```
 public class Member
    {
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        public int TeamID { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
    }
```

and i want to return below model from controller

```
public class Member
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}.
```

I have trying for something like below but not Team string remains null. I beleive i have to specify the mapping. But i am new to automapper i can't figure it out.

```
 IEnumerable<Models.Member> ienumerableDest = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.Member>, List<Models.Member>>(members);
```

Here is the [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P7GL.png)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have checked and done something like                 IEnumerable<Models.Member> ienumerableDest = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.Member>, IEnumerable<Models.Member>>(members); but how can i specify a ForMember functionality  as i showed for a single as mentioned in my question.

Comment: You've already done that correctly.

Comment: then why the Team string is empty.? i think i have not specified the mapping how can it map

Comment: try to use IList instead of IEnumerable. are you sure that `Team.Name` in `members` is not null? show us how do you get `members`

Comment: i have change as you suggested .. but i wonder how can it work since the Team string in destination and in source it is a complete object. that's why i showed how i acheive for a single entity

Comment: Probably `Team` is null. Try to make a repro.

Comment: @tiger show us how do you get members

Comment: @RomanMarusyk,, thanks i missed it there. I am really thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you haven't specified anywhere how to map your classes.

In your Entities.Member class you have a Team property of type Team, but you are trying to map it to string, so it fails.

In your configuration, add a profile which specifies this mapping, like this:

```
 public class AppProfile : Profile
    {
        public AppProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Entities.Member, Model.Member>(MemberList.Destination)
                .ForMember(d => d.Team, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Team.Name));
        }
    }
```

In this example i assumed a property "Name" in your Team object.

And in your startup class you should register your profile in your AutoMapper configuration.

Comment: Your suggestion looks good but it is for a single entity. I have to specify mapping for collection like,  CreateMap<IEnumerable<Entities.Member>,IEnumerable<Model.Member>>

Comment: That's the thing with AutoMapper. It handles lists mapping for you. You just have to define the single object mapping. It then maps each element by its own. Read the docs here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html.

Comment: thanks..Actually i missed it while returning for collection. I thought i would have to specify it seperatly.